# Why do I get a low accuracy in this neural network (tensorflow)?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have made a convolutional neural network with tensorflow, i've trained it and tested it (about 98% accuracy)... I saved the model with

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, 'model.ckpt')
```

Then i restored with the saver, but i always get an accuracy lower than 50%... why ?
Here's the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import numpy as np

with open('X_train.pickle', 'rb') as y:
    u = pickle._Unpickler(y)
    u.encoding = 'latin1'
    X_train = u.load()

with open('X_test.pickle', 'rb') as y:
    u = pickle._Unpickler(y)
    u.encoding = 'latin1'
    X_test = u.load()
    X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(-1, 2500)

with open('y_train.pickle', 'rb') as y:
    u = pickle._Unpickler(y)
    u.encoding = 'latin1'
    y_train = u.load()

with open('y_test.pickle', 'rb') as y:
    u = pickle._Unpickler(y)
    u.encoding = 'latin1'
    y_test = u.load()

n_classes = 3
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 2500])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

keep_rate = 0.8
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

def maxpool2d(x):
    #                        size of window         movement of window
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')



def convolutional_neural_network(x):
    weights = {'W_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32])),
               'W_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,64])),
               'W_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([13*13*64,1024])),
               'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))}

    biases = {'b_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
               'b_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
               'b_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
               'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 50, 50, 1])

    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)

    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)

    fc = tf.reshape(conv2,[-1, 13*13*64])
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc'])+biases['b_fc'])
    #fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate)

    output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out'])+biases['out']

    return output


def use_neural_network(input_data):
    prediction = convolutional_neural_network(x)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    result = (sess.run(tf.argmax(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:[input_data]}),1)))

    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
    print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:X_test, y:y_test}))

    return result

with tf.Session() as sess:

    c = convolutional_neural_network(x)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(sess, "model.ckpt")

    sample = X_train[432].reshape(2500) 
    res = use_neural_network(sample)

    if res == [0]: print('Go straight')
    elif res == [1]: print('Turn right')
    else: print('Turn left')

    img = sample.reshape(50,50)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()

    sample = X_train[1222].reshape(2500) 
    res = use_neural_network(sample)

    if res == [0]: print('Go straight')
    elif res == [1]: print('Turn right')
    else: print('Turn left')

    img = sample.reshape(50,50)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()


    sample = X_train[2986].reshape(2500) 
    res = use_neural_network(sample)

    if res == [0]: print('Go straight')
    elif res == [1]: print('Turn right')
    else: print('Turn left')

    img = sample.reshape(50,50)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

The problem can't be overfitting, since i'm testing it with elements of the training dataset ...
I'm quite sure that the problem is the saver, but i can't figure out how to solve it ...

Comment: Your loading the model is not right. I have answered it in:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873204/how-to-predict-with-meta-and-checkpoint-files-in-tensorflow/44876333#44876333

Answer (score 1):

When you train a model using tensorlfow , make sure that your using the **tensorflow version 1.0 and above.** once you trained model using latest version **3** file will be created named as follows :

1. modelname.**data**

   It is TensorBundle collection, save the values of all variables.
2. modelname.**index**

   .index stores the list of variable names and shapes saved.
3. modelname.**meta**

   this file describes the saved graph structure, includes GraphDef, SaverDef, and so on.

To reload/restore your model use **model.load(modelname)** it not only loads your model but also the accuracy won't be fluctuated.

**Note :** Please use **TFLearn** , TFLearn introduces a High-Level API that makes neural network building and training fast and easy.For more detail visit http://tflearn.org/getting_started/

The simple and Generalized way of building and using CNN using tensorflow is as follows:

**Construct Network :**

```
  Here your will create n convolution , max-poll layer and fully connected layer then apply whatever activation function you want and return your model object
```

**Train model :**

```
   fit your training data into your model using model.fit(X,Y)
```

**Save Model :**

```
   Save your model using model.save(modelName)
```

**Reload Model :**

```
   Reload your model using model.load(modelName)
```

This is the generic and simplified way to build and use CNN.

Hope it may help you :)